# JTable Not Appearing

Tags: java, swing, jtable, layout-manager

Whenever I set the panel's Layout to `FlowLayout`, the `JTable` appears, however my `imageBackground` and buttons are misplaced. And when I set the layout to null, the the table doesn't appear, but the buttons and `imageBackground` are where I wanted them to be. What am I'm going to do with this?

```
public class AssetPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    private ArrayList<AssetDetails> assetList;
    private Frame frame;
    private Database db;

    private JTable assetTable;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;

    private JButton btnBack;
    private JButton btnView;

    public AssetPanel (Frame frame){
        super();
        this.frame = frame;
        initialize();
    }

    public void initialize(){
        setName("Assets");
        setSize(700, 475);
        setLayout(null);
        setVisible(true);

        db = new Database();

        btnView = new JButton("View");
        btnView.addActionListener(this);
        btnView.setBounds(450, 400, 90, 20);
        add(btnView);

        btnBack = new JButton("Back");
        btnBack.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        btnBack.setBounds(550, 400, 90, 20);
        btnBack.addActionListener(this);
        add(btnBack);

        ImageIcon imageBackground = new ImageIcon(AssetPanel.class.getResource("/resources/assets.png"));
        JLabel jlBackground  = new JLabel(imageBackground);
        jlBackground.setBounds(0,0, 700, 475);
        add(jlBackground);
        initializeTable();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        if(ae.getSource() == btnBack){
            frame.changePanel("Main Menu");
        }
    }

    public void initializeTable(){
        Object[][] assetData;
        assetList = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] columnNames = {"Asset Name", "Date Acquired", "Type", "Classification"};
        assetList = db.getAssetTable();

        assetData = new Object[assetList.size()][columnNames.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < assetList.size(); i++){
            assetData[i][0] = assetList.get(i).getAssetName();
            assetData[i][1] = assetList.get(i).getDateAcquired();
            assetData[i][2] = assetList.get(i).getType();
            assetData[i][3] = assetList.get(i).getClassification();
        }

        assetTable = new JTable(assetData, columnNames);
        assetTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(400, 100));
        assetTable.setLocation(150, 100);
        assetTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(assetTable);
        add(scrollPane);
    }
}
```

Comment: what issues are you having when your flowlayout is set, what gets squished where?

Comment: _What am I going to do with this?_ Use a [layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Comment: You probably want to use a JLayeredPane.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a null layout or use the setBounds() method to position and size components.

> however my imageBackground and buttons are misplaced

A background is a Container component. That is you create it as a component and paint an image as the background. Then you add other components to the background component. Now the image will appear in the background and the other components appear on top of it.

See the [Background Panel](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/) to give an example of creating a background component.

Answer (score 0):

On possible solution:  I recommend switching to Mig Layout as a solution to all java layout problems.  I now use it for the layout of every single container component in my apps.  If you switch you'll probably be glad you did (will never again have problems like that listed in this question).

http://www.miglayout.com/

MigLayout may be included in the JDK in a future version of java.

Answer (score 0):

null layouts mean you have to explicitly place all the components.

I recommend BoxLayout.  it's really simple, and you can put in spacers to create space between objects, and glue to fill in all remaining space.

you can also nest the boxes, as well.

if you look at java sample code (and at the source for things); 
they nest a lot of JPanels to get the complicated layouts.

Answer (score 0):

**Try adding this before trying the steps below if it does not work:**

```
// Set your flow layout thus:
setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT,5,5));

// Set your table Auto Resize Mode to OFF
assetTable.setAutoResizeMode(assetTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
```

**EXTRA: Try if above tips does not help**

- Technically, your class should extend a JFrame.
  Add a root layout to the class(i.e. the JFrame):

`setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT,5,5))`;

- Create two panels; one should contain your label and buttons components.
  The other should contain the JScrollPane that contains your table.
  Both panels can have their Layout which determines how the components will be laid out.
  You can use FlowLayout.
- Then you can add both panels to the mother layout (JFrame).